# How do I submit a form using image links to change form action with JS (no JQuery)?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a search form that needs to be processed 3 different ways:

1) The default action of the form should submit using the return/enter key.

2) If "image1" is clicked the `$which_action` variable needs to be updated and submit the form.

3) if "image2" is clicked the `$which_action` variable needs to be updated and submit the form.

(I know the `$which_action` does not exist in the client browser, I have just included it as a placeholder in the following code)

Here is what I currently have with some notes on what I'd like to do:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $which_action ?>" id="query"> 
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['query']; ?>" />
</form>

<image1>clicking this image should change $which_action=image1.php and POST the form value into $_POST['query'] while submitting the form.
<image2>clicking this image should change $which_action=image2.php and POST the form value into $_POST['query'] while submitting the form.
```

The javascript should not effect the default method of submitting the form with the enter/return key.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to dynamically change the action of the form, but not with JavaScript? Good luck.

Comment: Is this a request, a question and what do you want exactly?

Comment: @frits: With just Javascript, not using Jquery library.

Comment: You have a few problems with you code: **1)** For starters if you want that field to post as `$_POST['query']`, the text input needs to have a **name** attribute supplied and it needs to be `query`. **2)** There is no changing `$which_action` as you say above. You can change the form ***action*** with JavaScript if that's what you're talking about. However, after your script executes and your code is output, to the client browser, the PHP variable `$which_action` no longer exists.

Comment: @War10ck: Thank you, yes that is basically what I would like to do.  I am aware the php variable $which_action doesn't exist in the client browser. I was using it in the code example as a placeholder. I just don't know how to write the javascript portion to do this.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <form method="POST" action="" id="query"> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['query']; ?>" />
</form>

 <img src="" onclick="changeAction('image1.php')">
 <img src="" onclick="changeAction('image2.php')">

 <script>
   function changeAction(url) {
   document.getElementById("query").action = url;
   document.getElementById("query").submit();
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I need but clicking on the image needs doesn't seem to update $_POST['query'] with the value that's in the form??

Comment: That's simply not possible... Javascript runs in the client while PHP runs in the server. If you mean that after posting the form, in the PHP script you are not receiving the value in $_POST['query'] that's because you need to add  - name="query" - to the input field

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianteres/mLBxR/

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $which_action ?>" id="query"> 
  <input id="the_input" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['query']; ?>" />
</form>

<image1 onclick="changeValue("foo")>
<image2 onclick="changeValue("bar")>

<script>
  window.changeValue = function (val) {
     document.getElementById("the_input").value = val;   
  }
</script>
```

Within that function you could search for the form (with an id) and change the action attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't want to change the form value="", I want to keep the form value (whatever the user types in) and just change the form action="".  When the user clicks the image the it should submit the form with the new action.